# How to install Ubuntu-Touch on Xiaomi Mi A3

Tags: linux, xiaomi, mi

H!@all
I would like to install the [Ubuntu-Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io/) on my [Xiaomi Mi A3](https://www.mi.com/in/mi-a3/)
How to start, were to download, how to flash?

1. The **Xiaomi Mi A3** is on the list of supported devices and a link to **Github** from where you can (I suspect) download the source code.
2. The [Ubports-installer](https://ubports.com/) is not working for the **Xiaomi Mi A3** (no install script).
3. So I download the source code [lunecrash-master.zip](https://github.com/mintphin/lunecrash)

Did i do everything right?
How to proceed?

Comment: [Als-Lunecrash-20200605-2206.zip](https://github.com/mintphin/lunecrash/releases/download/20200605/Als-Lunecrash-20200605-2206.zip), [dtbo.img](https://github.com/mintphin/lunecrash/releases/download/20200605/dtbo.img), [Installation](https://github.com/mintphin/lunecrash/wiki/Installation)